# How to create a virtual file system in Java/Kotlin with root in specific real directory?

Tags: java, kotlin, filesystems, nio, vfs

I need a virtual file system that a directory of host file system as its own root. Whatever path the VFS is asked to resolve, it should never go beyond the specified directory host's directory. For example:

```java
FileSystem fs = new CustomFileSystem(Paths.of("/some/directory/path")) // a real directory in host's FS.

fs.getPath("./test")     // "/some/directory/path/test"
fs.getPath("/")          // "/some/directory/path"
fs.getPath("../../test") // "/some/directory/path/test" not "/some/test"
```

I looked and the standard `FileSystems.newFileSystem()` but it seems to be working with files only. Same does Apache Commons VFS. It just extends the number of supported archive formats.

Is there any standard way to create such vfs, or the only way is custom implementation of `FileSystem` or/and `FileSystemProvider`?

Comment: I haven't noticed previously, but Apache Commons VFS seems to have [Local FIles](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/filesystems.html#Local_Files). It looks like what I need. But i'm not sure if it forces root directory. Will check later if it does what I need.